# Greater Power Attack

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, fighter, mythic-adventures

I'm using a 14th liv two-hand fighter with 5 Mythic tiers that allow him to add the Mythic Feat: Power Attack (Mythic) to Power Attack.
When a two-handed fighter makes a full-attack with a two-handed weapon, his damage roll with Strength 32 (mod +11) so reach:

11 x 1.5 = 16 for the first strike and
11 x 2 = 22 for all attacks after the first (due to Backswing) and adding Power Attack:
(without consider other feats or abilities or weapon)

11 x 1.5=16 + 4.5 (or 9, or 13, or 18 if using Power Attack maximum) for the first strike and
11 x 2 = 22 + 4.5 (or 9, or 13, or 18 if using Power Attack maximum) for all attacks after the first (due to Backswing)

And what's happen when he reaches 15° liv and gain Greater Power Attack?

from the text I understand:
11 x 1.5=16 + 6 (or 12, or 18, or 24 if using Power Attack maximum) for the first strike and
11 x 2 = 22 + 6 (or 12, or 18, or 24 if using Power Attack maximum) for all attacks after the first (due to Backswing)

It's all correct?

Thank you

Comment: KRyan: How Can I contact you in a chat? The problem is that I don't understand the Power Attack in the whole rules, so I want to ask you to chat a bit cause I ve a cascade of question about it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your numbers seem to be correct

Power Attack (Mythic) provides +3 damage until BAB 6, increased by 50% to 4 (4.5 rounds down) with a Two-handed weapon, then

- +6(+9) damage at BAB 6-10
- +9(+13) damage at BAB 11-15
- +12(+18) damage at BAB 16+

**Greater Power Attack** increases the number in parenthesis to

- +9(+18) damage at BAB 15
- +12 (+24) damage at BAB 16+

**Your total bonus damage** with two-handed Greater Power Attack(Mythic) at 15 BAB and +11 Strength is

- (11*1.5|2) = 16|22[Str] + 18[PA] + 3[Weapon Training] = 37 for your first swing then 43 after

> [Power Attack](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Power%20Attack)
> **Benefit:** You can choose to take a –1 penalty on all melee attack rolls and combat maneuver checks to **gain a +2 bonus on all melee damage rolls. This bonus to damage is increased by half (+50%)** if you are making an attack with a two-handed weapon, a one handed weapon using two hands, or a primary natural weapon that adds 1-1/2 times your Strength modifier on damage rolls. [...] When your base attack bonus reaches +4, and every 4 points thereafter, the penalty increases by –1 **and the bonus to damage increases by +2.** ...

Mythic:

> **Benefit:** **When you use Power Attack, you gain a +3 bonus on melee damage rolls instead of +2.** When your base attack bonus reaches +4 and every 4 points thereafter, **the amount of bonus damage increases by +3 instead of +2.** ...

> **[Greater Power Attack](https://www.aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Fighter%20Two-Handed%20Fighter) (Ex):** At 15th level, when using Power Attack with a two-handed melee weapon, **the bonus damage from Power Attack is doubled (+100%) instead of increased by half (+50%).** This ability replaces armor training 4.

Comment: Ifusaso: Sorry, not enough clear to me, probably I ve wrong basic information about Power Attack: I think: If I use Power Attack, I can choose if doing with -1 on attack roll, or -2, or -3, or -4 and then I got +6 or +12 or +18 or +24...

Comment: @alemayo Actually that's not right. You cannot choose to take less penalty for less damage, you can only choose to use Power Attack or not (at the maximum effect) "When your base attack bonus reaches +4, and every 4 points thereafter, the penalty increases by –1 and the bonus to damage increases by +2. " Lacks the words 'you may'